# How to send data from Flask to JS?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

Sorry I am really new to Flask, and I have encountered this issue while I was trying to pass data from Python Flask to JS in the front end:

app.py

```
@app.route("/",methods=['POST', 'GET'])    
def search():
    data = {"username": "test", "site": "stackoverflow.com"}
    return render_template('search.html',data=data)
```

search.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/search.js')}}"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

search.js

```
console.log(data)
```

and the result I got from the console was

```
ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

Please send help & love!! Thanks